# Azure Web App (Linux - Node v12 LTS) - 403 Request Header Too Long

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-ad-b2c, http-status-code-403

No idea where else to turn at this point. We're in the final stages of developing our app, which is hosted in a Linux-based NodeJS v12 Azure Web App.

Our app hooks up to Azure AD B2C to store and manage user accounts. AD B2C is configured entirely with Custom Policies.

When we try to change our account's password via B2C, we proceed with the password change successfully, but then B2C tries to redirect us back to our website, and it fails with a 431.

The Referer is ridiculously long, and looks something like this:   `https://%ADTenant%.b2clogin.com/%ADTenant%.onmicrosoft.com/%CustomPolicyName%/api/SelfAsserted/confirmed?csrf_token=%Token%&tk=StateProperties=%Token%&p=%CustomPolicyName%?diags=%ListOfEncodedClaimsAndControlInformation%`

Encoded, the entire thing is roughly ~1,800-1,900 characters long. We also have about ~1,000-1,100 characters in our cookies, and the destination URL is ~1,300 characters long, for a total of ~4.1-4.3k characters.

If we reload the page the referer becomes empty so the call works fine.
Strangely enough, when in Incognito, the issue does not arise; the Referer becomes empty and it works fine.

At first we thought it was the NodeJS 8KB request header size maximum, but our request header is under that. And it works locally; it only breaks when the app is in an Azure Web App, making it harder to troubleshoot.

We even added `WEBSITE_AUTH_DISABLE_IDENTITY_FLOW=true` to our Web App: no luck

If anyone out there has an idea, that would be amazing, as we're running thin on ideas here :(
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can try use `–max-http-header-size` arg for node.

Comment: We've tried it and it doesn't seem to work. We've used that argument to reduce the max header size to something ridiculously low where it should've broken in our local environment, and it would still go true :/

Comment: Hmm.. In my case, work fine, but I choose Azure Web Apps (Windows), and my web.config include args as follows: 
<httpPlatform processPath=”node” arguments=”–max-http-header-size=16384 server.js”/>

Comment: Yeah we're on Linux, and we did try changing our startup command to `node server/server.js --max-http-header-size 80000`, but it didn't solve our issue :(

Comment: We also noticed later on that the issue only happens if we're already logged into the user account, because it carries session cookies. If the user is logged out and resets its password (same backend process and policy as a password change), the error doesn't happen because the session cookie isn't present.